# how to get which webservice is calling a method

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a webservice 'mywebservice' and a web method 'mywebmethod' defined in it.
This web method calls a function 'callme()' which is defined in another class.
I want to get the service name which is calling this function and also the methodname. I want this in 'callme()' function.

--'mywebservice.asmx.cs'

```
[WebMethod]
public void mywebmethod
{
     callme();
}
```

-- 'class1.cs'

```
public void callme()
{
     // --- I want service name(mywebservice) & methodname(mywebmethod) here.
}
```

Comment: if it is your implementation of class1.cs what is stopping you passing these parameters from each webmethod calling it, obviously this is not the best way, but based on the details in this question this looks like most obvious. `Provide more details and what have you tried for better responses`

Comment: I dont want to pass parameters from webmethod. I just want to get the method and service name which is calling this function.

Comment: why? in both the cases? why dont you want to pass parameters? why you want service name and method in called method? The reason for these whys is to understand the real problem.

Comment: The condition is that, I cant modify the webservice/webmethod. I can modify callme(). So I can get the calling methodname there. I think its pretty simple, I just dont know how to do it.

Comment: what do you want to do with the `methodname`, perhaps the purpose could be achieved in other easier ways. Look at [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) you might get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way could be to use [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class (see example section to get started) to walk back to call stack to get type name & method name - this will give you the names for class/method implementing the service.

Mind you that stack trace construction is an expensive operation - as such, I would recommend to pass necessary information as parameters to the method. Further, if you could state why you need this information (service & method name), you may get an better answer to solve your actual problem.